# 2TB family plan - want to move GF to her own plan

Tags: icloud

I have the max 2TB plan. My GF is part of my plan. However (both photographers) we're maxing out the 2TB limit.

Instead of paying an ungodly sum for the Apple+ (which we won't use) to get the extra 2TB - I'd rather just sign her up for her own 2TB iCloud storage.

How can I accomplish this, and move her 350,000 photo over to her account?

Thanks!
:)

Comment: There are many solutions already available.

Comment: @thinkr If there are, wouldn‘t this make a good answer?

Comment: @nohillside I was going to do this but I noticed in the meantime that my answer won't work since it would transfer ***all*** of the photos instead of "only" 350,000.

Comment: @Thinkr, your method would _copy_ all, or move all, leaving the original account empty?  If it _copies_ all, then each person would be able to delete the other person's photos as quickly or slowly as they wish.

Comment: @WGroleau Yeah, the idea was to *copy* them (I think). I don’t really remember what I was going to propose now but I think it’s that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic way to do this, unfortunately.

- Have your GF sign up for her own 2TB plan
- Download her photos in full quality to a NAS or similar with your account
- Ask her to import those photos into her iCloud account
- Verify that all photos have been imported, then delete them from your account and empty the trash

Answer (score -1):

If you are subscribing to the 2TB plan and sharing it with your GF, then the steps to split this up:

1. She should subscribe to her own 2TB plan
2. You can stop sharing your 2TB plan in iCloud Family Sharing settings